# Grouping SSRS report on multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a report we will call ReportOne, in this ReportOne I am querying the data for this report with a stored procedure. The stored procedure query returns two values which are 'TravelDate' and 'Status'.

My report has four fields, 'BeginDate', 'EndDate', 'Status', and 'Days'.

My issue is this, I need to group the report by both the 'Status' and consecutive days. Consecutive days coming from TravelDate.

'BeginDate' will be the first new date

'EndDate' will be the last consecutive date.

'Status' will be status.

'Days' will be the number of consecutive days.

Example,

```
TravelDate | Status

1/1/2001   | Leave
1/2/2001   | Leave
1/3/2001   | Leave
1/5/2001   | Leave
1/6/2001   | Travel
```

The report will then look as follows.

```
BeginDate | EndDate  | Status | Days

1/1/2001  | 1/3/2001 | Leave  | 3

1/5/2001  | 1/5/2001 | Leave  | 1

1/6/2001  | 1/6/2001 | Travel | 1
```

Comment: Best if you format the sample data as you did the desired results

Comment: This is a standard Gaps-and-Islands problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([TravelDate] date,[Status] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('1/1/2001','Leave')
,('1/2/2001','Leave')
,('1/3/2001','Leave')
,('1/5/2001','Leave')
,('1/6/2001','Travel')


Select BeginDate=min(TravelDate)
      ,EndDate  =max(TravelDate)
      ,Status   =max(Status)
      ,Days     =datediff(DAY,min(TravelDate),max(TravelDate))+1
 From (
        Select * 
              ,Grp = DateDiff(DAY,'1900-01-01',TravelDate) - row_number() over (partition by status order by TravelDate)
         From @YourTable
      ) A
 Group By Grp
 Order By BeginDate
```

**Returns**

```
BeginDate   EndDate     Status  Days
2001-01-01  2001-01-03  Leave   3
2001-01-05  2001-01-05  Leave   1
2001-01-06  2001-01-06  Travel  1
```

**EDIT -- Capture from Stored Procedure  -- @YourTable Structure must match the Structure of Stored Procedure**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([TravelDate] date,[Status] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable 
Exec youStoredProcedure

    Select BeginDate=min(TravelDate)
          ,EndDate  =max(TravelDate)
          ,Status   =max(Status)
          ,Days     =datediff(DAY,min(TravelDate),max(TravelDate))+1
     From (
            Select * 
                  ,Grp = DateDiff(DAY,'1900-01-01',TravelDate) - row_number() over (partition by status order by TravelDate)
             From @YourTable
          ) A
     Group By Grp
     Order By BeginDate
```

**EDIT - Nested Subquery**

```
Select BeginDate=min(TravelDate)
      ,EndDate  =max(TravelDate)
      ,Status   =max(Status)
      ,Days     =datediff(DAY,min(TravelDate),max(TravelDate))+1
 From (
        Select * 
              ,Grp = DateDiff(DAY,'1900-01-01',TravelDate) - row_number() over (partition by status order by TravelDate)
         From (
                -- Your Query Here --- 
              ) A
      ) A
 Group By Grp
 Order By BeginDate
```

**EDIT - Consumed from a TVF**

```
Select BeginDate=min(TravelDate)
      ,EndDate  =max(TravelDate)
      ,Status   =max(Status)
      ,Days     =datediff(DAY,min(TravelDate),max(TravelDate))+1
 From (
        Select * 
              ,Grp = DateDiff(DAY,'1900-01-01',TravelDate) - row_number() over (partition by status order by TravelDate)
         From [dbo].[YourTableValedFunction](Param1,Param2) src
      ) A
 Group By Grp
 Order By BeginDate
```

Comment: I see that this solution produces the results needed for this specific example. I may be overlooking something simple as I am not that good with SQL but I am pulling the values I used in the example from a stored procedure query being done. How would i go about formatting that into this query where the values are essentially hard coded.

Comment: I mentioned in the original question that I am querying using a stored procedure. That procedure is using 2 parameters, one being SocialSecurityNumber and the other being an OrderNumber.

Comment: @GustavoBarragan In the updated answer, I included an example on how to capture the results from a stored procedure.  You may want to consider converting the stored procedure to a Table-Valued Function.   TVF make it easier to consume the results in different ways.

Comment: @GustavoBarragan Added a Consumed from TVF.    Well worth your time getting comfortable with TVFs  :)